# Is noise in a TL494 based push-pull converter causing low duty cycle?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, noise, push-pull

I have assembled a push-pull converter based on a TL494. Here is the circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKWhNV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

`V1` is a 12 volt battery, `V2` is the reference regulator in the TL494.

Not shown are two 1000 ohm resistors connecting Pin 1 (1IN+) and Pin 2(1IN-) to `V_ref` and ground. This disables one of the error amplifiers.

I have temporarily disabled `R11` by shorting it.

I have temporarily disabled the other error amplifier by shorting `R6`.

The diode `D1` and the capacitor `C1` are a protection network for the MOSFET. The same exists on `M2` but is not depicted for brevity.

Varying `R9` allows the operating frequency to be changed.

`XFRM1` is a small coil I made with 20 turns total on the primary and 10 turns on the secondary. The voltage should be approximately unity. `R10` is the load in this case, I also have a LED and a resistor to visually indicate the presence of current.

Powering up this circuit heats `R10`, so it works. I've also looked at both gates on the MOSFETs and they are actually relatively clean. The problem is I cannot get the dead time to an acceptable value. The duty cycle never goes above 75%. I was concerned I was getting noise from a switching power supply, so that is why `V1` is a battery. I thought perhaps that voltage induced into the circuit from `XFMR1` was causing issues, so I disconnected the supply from `V1`. The duty cycle does not change.

I scoped `V1` and `V2` and found noise. There is also noise on the ramp oscillator, one leg of `C2`. To try and eliminate this I added a 10 pF cap directly between `VCC` and `GND` on the chip. I also added a `20nF` cap to `V1` down on the board. I've also tried temporarily adding other capacitors  of various values with no change. All the way from 10 pF up to 47 nF.

In the scope traces below I am triggering the scope on CH1, the gate of one of the MOSFETs.

Here is the scope shot of `V1` with AC coupling

[image]

Here is the scope shot of `V2` (the reference regulator) with AC coupling

[image]

Here is the scope shot of the ramp oscillator

[image]

Here is the scope shot of the dead time control (DTC) pin

[image]

Here is the scope shot of the ground pin on the chip

[image]

As you can see, the MOSFET gate voltage does not change until the ramp oscillator is about 25% of the along its oscillation. Is the noise in the circuit the cause of this, or should I be checking elsewhere? What are the possible sources of the noise in this circuit? Keep in mind I have `XFMR` disconnected from `V1` in all the above scope shots. So this circuit is only charging and discharging the gates.

Here is a physical shot of the setup

[image]

**Update**

I disconnected the gates of the MOSFETs, this reduces the current in the circuit to almost zero. This should eliminate the opportunity for any noise induced the from high currents in the gate circuits. I measured the emitters of the TL494 directly with my scope. I see the same behavior, so something other than noise from the gate current is preventing the correct operation of the TL494.

Comment: Probably your non-insulated shoes, you should always wear insulated shoes when working with electricity!  LOL

Comment: But seriously, I looked high and low in your schematic and didn't see a TL494, why not have it in the schematic to make things easier?

Comment: I could not determine how to draw a DIP8 in the editor.

Comment: If you have ever scoped sub 100ns risetimes on a scope with long ground leads, you should have noticed inductive overshoot error.  This is what happens when your layout has long ground leads and switched current leads.  Try to keep everything very short , use twisted pairs to a digital output ground separate from the analog ground which has FB , Vref , Vin and Vout.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Would making a circuit board for this be a better idea?

Comment: Breadboarding needs to be small, neat and tight layout for signal integrity. ground planes help absorb stray crosstalk, but still possible without a PCB if you try to mimic the tight layout. Although it is still possible to have a bad layout on a PCB. Follow demo board layouts for ideas.  For better measurements remove tip and  gnd clip and connect to two pins few mm apart with tip and barrel and make sure gnd is not a long wire.  Braid, Litz wire or bench foil gnd plane is better  with 1~3cm max gnd wires.

Comment: {Practise  with a 50 Ohm R on wires witha  perfect text square wave from a 50 Ohm source for textbook waves forms on long twisted pairs 50R load.} or use a CMOS 74ALC inverter source on long leads with 100R pull up and 100R to gnd and see the difference with no termination. on edge ringing. Practise balancing ( calibrating two 10:1 probes with no gnd wire except barrel to gnd pin on differential A-B sum measurements for flatline on the same pulse signal then you can trust it for differential probing with clean waveforms without measurement error.  try it on a 1m twisted pair vs flyleads

Comment: Then practice CM rejection with  a long wire from 9V battery to a 12V relay coil in series with NO contacts.  This will buzz and spew lots of dI/dt and dV/dt EH field noise near the loop area. Then repeat your differential 50 ohm measurements and try to eliminate the crosstalk EMI with CM choke around either emitting and receiving twisted pair cable with 50R termination to see the effects.  Then you will understand how to avoid such mistakes in future of inductively switched loads in SMPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much what I'd expect from breadboard - you are seeing 0V bounce and that will likely be the high currents inducing voltages in the large loop formed by the scope probe and it's respective earth wire. A really common problem faced when doing switch mode supplies. Here is a picture of what some folk do to avoid this problem: -

[image]

You can also buy scope attachments like this: -

[image]

Other things:

- If you expect D1 to somehow magically do something, forget it - the internal diode in the MOSFET will be much faster (even if there was something useful to do (which there isn't)).
- C1 (4n7 across drain the ground) is just a stealer of energy - you charge it up and then you discharge it hence an energy waster. If in fact you are trying to make a snubber to prevent spikes killing the FETs then I would recommend a zener diode in series with a conventional diode from each drain to the incoming power rail - at least then you salvage some energy in the flyback spike.

Anyway, they are your starting points as I see it.

Comment: Can you please include the name of the scope attachment?

Comment: It's just a probe accessory and all probe suppliers should sell you one.